# Is it possible to check if file exists in ftp before attaching it to email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I'm trying to attach a file from ftp directory to the email by using ampscript function AttachFile. Everything works fine as long as the file exists in ftp directory. If it doesn't exist the email is cancelled and it's not sent.

I need to perform an action when this error occurs (for example update a field in Data Extension or in Salesforce object) but I am not able to catch this run time error when the attachment wasn't found in ftp. Below is the code that uses SSJS try catch block but it doesn't work; action in catch block is not performed when email fails.

Does anyone have an idea is it possible to check if file exists in ftp directory or how to catch attachFile error?

```
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
  Platform.Load("core", "1.1.3");
  try{
</script>

%%[
  AttachFile('FTP', @FileName)
]%%

<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  } catch(e) { 
</script>

%%[
   SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('ContactCommunication__c', @Id, 'Status__c', 'Error'); 
   RaiseError("Don't send to subscriber", true)
]%%

<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: I really dont think the raise function works . A year ago it drove me insane. It would cancel the message, but i was never able to get it to write to a log

Comment: is it an option in your usecase to make the entire process start with a file drop automation? That way you would have a logical sequence that would never get to a sendout without the file.

Comment: @JonasLamberty imagine you have a million files each filename is the subsciberid of that subscriber. Each file is unique for the subscriber. Would you then start 1million automations? I tend to believe that this is not ideal :D and you would have to create 1 million automations because the trigger would need to be exclusive for one particular filename, else you would trigger it multiple times for each subscriber.

Comment: Yeah sure, I was coming from a usecase where the same attachment is used for all sendouts in a bulk scenario (like a paid publication). Since the OP didn't state a personalization requirement in the files, I asked if it is possible in their usecase. In your scenario it is not, I think we can all agree.